# Outputting the content of an array to a text file in C#

Tags: c#

I need your help.
I want to make a program where I give a number and it increments it as many times as I said and write output into a .txt file. I have an issue with writing it because it only writes one output. I know basics but I have never worked with more complicated coding, only a few games, and simple apps.

```
int baseNumber = int.Parse(tbBase.Text);
  
int codeNumber = int.Parse(tbCodeNumber.Text);
int[] codes = new int[codeNumber];
int count = 0;
string link = "https://www.roblox.com/groups/";
for (int i =0; i < codes.Length; i++)
{
    codes[i] = baseNumber++;
}
foreach (int element in codes)
{
    string text= $"{link}{Convert.ToString(codes[count])}";
    System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"D:\TextFiles\WriteText.txt", text);
    count++;
}
```

Comment: You can `Join` all items of `codes` in one string and then save it: `File.WriteAllText(@"D:\TextFiles\WriteText.txt", string.Join(", ", codes));`

Comment: I'll try, and reply about the results. Thank you for your fast response. Edit: It worked but can I make every generated code into a new line?

Comment: you can try by adding the newline escape sequence {string.Join("\n", codes)}.

Comment: @OSX: what is the desired file content, please? Suppose we have `baseNumber = 5` and `codeNumber = 3`

Comment: `File.WriteAllText(@"D:\TextFiles\WriteText.txt", string.Join(Environment.NewLine, codes));` if you want *new line* as a delimiter

Comment: It's working I made it for generating roblox group codes they are something like this: 
 ''baseNumber = 4184195' 'codeNumber = 20' @DmitryBychenko

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use this code . You wrote the number of for loops in the file, which is wrong. Put the text in a string and put it in the file

```
int baseNumber = int.Parse(tbBase.Text);
int codeNumber = int.Parse(tbCodeNumber.Text);
int[] codes = new int[codeNumber];
for (int i = 0; i < codes.Length; i++)
{
    codes[i] = baseNumber++;
}



int count = 0;
string text = "";
string link = "https://www.roblox.com/groups/";
foreach (int element in codes)
{
   text += $"{link}{Convert.ToString(codes[count])}";
   count++;
}

 string fileName = @"D:\WriteText.txt";
 if (File.Exists(fileName))
     System.IO.File.AppendAllText(fileName, text);
 else
     System.IO.File.WriteAllText(fileName, text);
```

Read text file for editing

```
public void ReadFile(string fileName)
{
   string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(fileName);

   // Display the file contents by using a foreach loop.
   string text = "";
   foreach (string line in lines)
   {
       // Use a tab to indent each line of the file.
       text += line + Environment.NewLine;
       Console.WriteLine("\t" + line);
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, it's working. Very helpful answer. Edit: how I can edit it so it outputs every generated code into new code?

Comment: I edited the post. If there is a file, it adds new text to the previous text.

Comment: I see thank you, I meant something different but no problem I can try to solve it myself.

Comment: I also included reading the file for editing.